# How to execute method in class using Gradle task?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

I want to execute Hello method in class using gradle task(at springboot). The sample is like below.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void Hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to execute Hello function in gradle task?

I had added below and tried but below task cannot parse MyClass token.

```
task myTest{
    doLast {
        println "Executing MyClass method"
        def v = new MyClass();
        v.Hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that class declared?

Comment: sry about late cheking. That is declared at src > main ... > Hello.java as a Java Code.